# SQLITE Date difference / Date substraction

Tags: sqlite

I got confused

```
select date('2016-12-31'), date('2016-12-31','-1 month'), date('2016-12-31','-2 month');
```

The result is

```
2016-12-31  2016-12-01  2016-10-31
```

Is there something I missed?
I'm expecting

```
2016-12-31  2016-11-31  2016-10-31
```

I need to get last date on each month.

Comment: Agree with Rahul...if you want to check it then try it>>"select date('2016-12-30'), date('2016-12-30', '-1 month'), date('2016-12-30','-2 month');"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) will clarify it well:

> Note that "±NNN months" works by rendering the original date into the
>   YYYY-MM-DD format, adding the ±NNN to the MM month value, then
>   normalizing the result. Thus, for example, the data 2001-03-31
>   modified by '+1 month' initially yields 2001-04-31, but April only has
>   30 days so the date is normalized to 2001-05-01.

Comment: I still don't get it. So if date is '2016-12-31' how to get 1 month back from this date which is '2016-11-31'?

Comment: And vice versa on the documentation 2001-03-31 modified by '+1 month' how to get it to be 2001-04-31 instead of 2001-05-01